# How do I delete a wordpress user from giant database?

Tags: users, admin

The native wordpress delete users page is unable to load for us, as we have hundreds of thousands of user accounts that it queries and loads into a drop down menu every time the page is loaded.  Essentially our wordpress site has gotten so big that it's impossible to delete a user account using worpress's built in tool.

I can delete the user directly from the database, but I also want to attribute their content to someone.  Is there another solution for deleting user accounts and attributing their content to another user?

Comment: Are you able to use WP CLI? https://wp-cli.org/

Comment: I've never used it but I believe its installed on our server. Can users be deleted and have their content reassigned via WP CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Using [WP CLI](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/), you can easily delete users without concerns about loading the WordPress UI.

[`wp user delete`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/delete/) is the command you're looking for.

In your case, use `wp user delete 123 --reassign=567` for deleting a user by ID and reassigning to another user.

Comment: I think I'll have to try this. I'll try to get caught up on using WP CLI